# Which bastards in Westeros were automatically legitimized once their parents married?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, laws

I was watching a discussion between Elio and Linda, co-authors of *The World of Ice and Fire* and founders of Westeros.org, on Annullments in Westeros, in light of recent developments in the show.

Linda says in that video:

> We do have an example of course from *The World of Ice and Fire* where
>   children who were produced prior to marriage were rendered legitimate
>   by  the marriage.

I realized that I didn't know which example is she talking about?

Which bastards were rendered legitimate upon their parents marriage in Westerosi History?

Comment: If even Aegon can't answer, who will ?

Comment: It's based on a lie /s

Comment: Is it the Sand Snakes?

Comment: @Möoz Sandsnakes are bastards aren't they? Oberyn never married any of their mothers. And why aren't you on Twitter? >D

Comment: @Edlothiad are you referring Robert's rebellion :)

Comment: @Kepotx Apparently the man in the video and co-author of TWOIAF ;)

Comment: @Kepotx nothing that a little WoG can't fix.

Comment: @Aegon for the next question we will try to summon G.R.R. Martin

Comment: @Skooba What do you mean by WoG ?

Comment: @Kepotx Word of god

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Linda's referring to a detail from George's material that was cut from *The World of Ice and Fire*, but will be appearing in *Fire and Blood*, relating to a situation where Lord Hightower took up with his step-mother following his father's death.

The High Septon refused to countenance the relationship and would not allow them to marry, but they continued it and had a number of children. Eventually a new High Septon allowed the marriage and the children were rendered legitimate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Elio! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer it yourself. Looking forward to Fire and Blood!

Comment: Is this what one would call a leak?

Comment: And if anyone's wondering, [this *is* in fact the real Elio](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8074/21267)